# Database mutable field

Tags: django, database, model

I have to store data, a part of them is predefined but the user can chose to custom it.
What is the best way to store these data in the database?

1. 2 fields, 1 will be an integer field for predefined option and the second will be a string for the custom user input
2. 1 string field, which will contains a json like {predefined: 2, custom: ''}
3. 1 string field which will contains custom string or predefined option id (converted during the request process)
4. 1 string field which will contains the fulltext option even if it is a predefined (some of these predefined options can be long text)

I tried the 1) but double the number of fields for each "custom ready" data doesn't seem to be perfect...

Any idea ?

Comment: An example would be nice. Which Django version and which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you might need the following (it's not very clear from your question):

1. a form where there is an input field for the customizable part of the string
2. an easy way to refer to the complete string
3. a way to administer/manage/validate the non-customizable string

=> use two fields:

```
class TheModel(Model):
    # if you have a certain constant number of choices, use ChoiceField
    # otherwise use a ForeingKey and create a different model for those
    non_customizable_prefix = ChoiceField(null=False, blank=False, ...)
    # unique? validators? max/min length? null/blank?
    customizable_part = CharField(...)

    @property
    def complete_string(self):
        return '{}{}'.format(self. non_customizable_prefix, self. customizable_part)
```

This model will provide you with two separate input fields in Django forms or the Django admin, offering easy ways to make the `non_customizable_prefix` read only or only modifiable with certain privileges.